# Unexpected bash assignment result using tr command

Tags: bash, shell, tr

This is the `bash` statement in question:

```
xx="$(echo 'a_b' | tr '_' '\t')"
```

Why is the underscore replaced with a space instead of a tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not.  :-)

If you check the result with `echo $xx`, the tab will be replaced with a space.

Try `echo "$xx"` (with double-quotes) instead.

Comment: Use More Quotes(TM), in other words.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly answering your question, but you can do this in pure Bash:

```
xx='a_b'
xx="${xx//_/    }"
```

(where the space in `/  }` is a literal <kbd>Tab</kbd>; you may need to use `^v` to enter it)

Comment: You have a typo in your second assignment statement: the `a_b` there is supposed to be `xx`. Also, instead of using a literal tab, I think it's clearer and easier to write `xx="${xx//_/$'\t'}"` (though you're welcome to disagree).

Comment: @ruakh Thanks.  I agree, but `$''` only works with `shopt -s extquote`, which may or may not be enabled.